# is it possible to Sum values grouped by month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by, sum

I have an SQL Server table structured as follows :

```
Table name : calendar.
```

Columns :

```
Calendar Date (smalldatetime)
Working Day (bit)
```

Calendar date has all dates, structured in the format yyyy-mm-dd.
Working day means that I have work if it is a 1, and if it is a weekend or a holiday it is marked as a 0.

What I want to retrieve :

```
Month      No Working Days   Year
------------------------------------
January    22                2011
February   20                2011
March      22                2011
...
December   10                2011
January    15                2012
```

All of the information is there, but I am just not sure how to write a query like this, but I assume it would be structured something similar to this with some fancy datetime functions thrown in. Does

```
SELECT Sum(Working Day)
       GROUP BY (Not a clue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are interested in finding the working days in each month in each year and report which month the number of days is for. This will give you that:

```
SELECT YEAR([Calendar Date]) As [YEAR],
       Month([Calendar Date]) As [Month],
       SUM([Working Day] As [Working Days]
FROM [Calendar]
GROUP BY YEAR([Calendar Date]), 
         Month([Calendar Date])
```

Comment: I like this answer, though everyones was correct. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT Sum(Working Day)
WHERE Working Day = 1
   GROUP BY MONTH(calenderDate)
```

This will group by month as you asked.
For more datetime functions your could check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(month, [Calendar Date]) 'Month',
    COUNT(1) 'No Working Days', 
    YEAR([Calendar Date]) 'Year'
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Working Day] = 1
GROUP BY DATENAME(month, [Calendar Date]), YEAR([Calendar Date])
```

Depending your data and your desired results, if a month doesn't have any working days, this query won't return any results for that month.  Instead, you could use something like this with `CASE` removing the `WHERE` criteria:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(month, [Calendar Date]) 'Month',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [Working Day] = 1 THEN 1 END) 'No Working Days', 
    YEAR([Calendar Date]) 'Year'
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DATENAME(month, [Calendar Date]), YEAR([Calendar Date])
```

You may not need the case statement at all -- depends on whether your table allows `NULL` for your bit field.  If it doesn't allow `NULLs`, you can just use `SUM([Working Day])` as it will sum 0s and 1s.

- [SQL Fiddle Demos](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26aac/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one… it’s pretty much the same as most answers above with the addition of order by

```
SELECT YEAR(calendar_date) As [Year],
MONTH(calendar_date) As [Month],
SUM(working_day) As Working_Days
FROM [calendar]
GROUP BY YEAR(calendar_date) MONTH(calendar_date]) 
ORDER BY [Year], [Month]
```